# What does sscanf do in C if the input doesn't meet the specified format?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char buffer[256];
    int n, a, b;
    n = a = b = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, 250, fp)) {
        n = sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &a, &b);
        printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, n);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Next Part\n");
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    n = a = b = 0;
    while (0 < (n = fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &a, &b))){
        printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

input.txt contains these lines:

```
1 2 3
4 abc 5 6
7 8
the 1 next 2 line 3 is blank

4 5 the above line is blank 6
7 8
```

I know the first printed line will be `1 2 2` because `n` was set to the return value of `sscanf` (which returned `2` since both integers were read I assume). I, however, am unsure of what the second line would produce? If I can get someone to work out and explain the second line for me, I would appreciate it. I am also confused on what will happen when the loop experiences a blank line?

Comment: `scanf` can be strange. A space in the format string means to skip over any whitespace. The input is not consumed from the input stream if the input cannot be used to satisfy the format specifier.

Comment: @jxh it's about `sscanf`, not `scanf`. There is no input stream.

Comment: True, @Jabberwocky, but pretty pedantic.  Remove "stream" from jxh's comment and it applies equally to `scanf` and `sscanf`.

Comment: How do *you* read [`sscanf`'s docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html)?  Those particular docs are a lot to take in, I know, but reading technical documentation is a skill you need to cultivate to become a good programmer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Why does that page show the bulk of the conversion specifiers as "deprecated"?  There's no deprecation of any `*scanf()` conversion specifiers mentioned in the draft C23 standard at https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html

Comment: That's a good question, @AndrewHenle.  I have no idea.  I prefer in general to link manual pages, because that removes the need to navigate a massive specification document, and in the past I have found that particular collection of them to be reliable, with the caveat that it does document the Glibc versions (which makes no difference to the present question).  But I agree, C has not deprecated any conversion specifiers.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thinking of the input string as a stream gives a better indication of what happens. Processing stops (the stream jams). As a string, it is harder to understand the jamming action.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I also see nothing in the latest `glibc` source from `git clone https://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git` that indicates any changes to `sscanf()`, much less deprecating any conversion specifiers.

Comment: I did not intend to suggest that there were any, @AndrewHenle.

Comment: @JohnBollinger My apologies.  I did not mean to imply that.  It does seem remarkably strange that the Linux man page for `sscanf()` would mark the majority of `*scanf()` conversion specifiers as deprecated with no driver from either the C standard or glibc.

Comment: I agree, @AndrewHenle.  I have no idea where that came from or what manner of processing failure might have produced that effect.

Answer (score 4):

> What does `sscanf` do in C if the input doesn't meet the specified format?

```
int sscanf(const char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

`sscanf()` processes the *format string* `format` a character at a time if not `%`.  Otherwise it reads a single scan *specifier* (like `"%d"`). These are processed against the string `s`, but no further than the end of string `s`.  `sscanf()` then continues likewise down `format` until a *null character* is read or scan *specifier* conversions fails.  Then:

- The scanning stops.
- Subsequent parts of `format` are not used.
- There is no further change to the number of conversions (the return value).
- `...` arguments not yet used are left unread so whatever they point to is not assigned.
- `sscanf()` returns the conversion count.

Comment: You should mention that whitespace in the format string match any sequence of whitespace in the string, including none.

Comment: @chqrlie Perhaps, yet then I'm starting the drive down `*scanf()` specifications lane, one of the longest in the C spec.   One could write a tome on that drive. (Note: a space in `"%[ ]"` only matches a _space_, so "whitespace in the format string match any sequence of whitespace" needs qualifications).

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly the `sscanf` documentation is tedious to read.

This small example shows what happens if the input does not match the format string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a = 100, b = 200;
  char input1[] = "1 2 3 4 whatever";
  int n = sscanf(input1, "%d %d", &a, &b);
  printf("sscanf has read %d items. a = %d, b = %d\n", n, a, b);

  char input2[] = "11 foo bar";
  n = sscanf(input2, "%d %d", &a, &b);
  printf("sscanf has read %d items. a = %d, b = %d\n", n, a, b);
}
```

The output is:

```
sscanf has read 2 items. a = 1, b = 2
sscanf has read 1 items. a = 11, b = 2
```

During the first `sscanf`, 2 items have been read as `1` and `2` match the `%d %d` format string.

During the second `sscanf`, only 1 item has been read as only `11` matches the first `%d`, but `foo` does not match the second `%d`. `b` is not modified.

It let you figure out what `sscanf` does if you feed it a blank line. Hint: it's not totally obvious, but it's in the documentation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica done.

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure if this is right, but I’m going to say that n = 0 when the loop encounters the blank line?

Comment: @ALumpkin: not really. For a blank line, with or without white space characters such as a newline, `sscanf()` trying to parse an `int` for `%d` will read and consume initial whitespace and reach the end of the string before the first conversion can produce an `int`, hence `sscanf()` will return `EOF`.  (the answer is in the documentation but it's not totally obvious IMHO)